# GRUB: Boot from ISO file

Tags: grub2, iso

I have the following /etc/grub.d/40_custom file on Fedora 32:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry "Start Fedora-KDE-Live 33" --class fedora {
 set isofile="/Fedora-KDE-Live-x86_64-33-1.2.iso"
 loopback loop (lvm/fedora-home)/sergio/Descargas/Distros$isofile
 linuxefi (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz iso-scan/filename=${isofile} root=live:CDLABEL=Fedora-KDE-Live-33-1-2  rd.live.image
 initrdefi (loop)/isolinux/initrd.img
 }
```

I have used that configuration a few years ago, but now it does not work. If I choose that grub entry the screen goes in black (and does not display any error at all) and I have to reboot and choose another grub entry.

Note: The inclusion of parameter `rd.live.debug=1` does not change anything. And dracut tells me that lvm modules is included:

```
lsinitrd -m | grep lvm
lvm
```

Is there something wrong or missing in my custom file?

Comment: Similar? https://superuser.com/questions/479040/from-grub2-boot-an-iso-in-an-lvm2-logical-volume

Comment: @oldfred nice try, marked solution it says the same in another way, however the problem reported there is different, I haven't any error messages.